# Global hooks with iron:router v1.0

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am attempting to create a global hook that checks if a **user is logged in**, if so, **check that the "userData" publication has completely been sent down the wire.** 
This is because a lot of my code is dependant on this publication and I want to prevent getting undefined objects (templates being rendered before it has necessary data).

Is the following the correct way to declare this default behaviour on all routes?

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
layoutTemplate: 'appBody',

loadingTemplate: 'appLoading',

onBeforeAction: function () {
 if (!Meteor.user()) {
   this.render('login');
 } else {
   this.next();
 }
},
waitOn: function(){
 return Meteor.subscribe('userData');
},
 action: function () {
  if (this.ready()) //if subscription handle is ready, continue
  this.next();
  else  // otherwise show appLoading template
  this.render('appLoading');
   }
 });
```

Global config:

```
Router.configure({
controller: 'ApplicationController'
});
```

server.js
Need the client always subscribed 'userData' if they are logged in.

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
    {fields: {'somefield': 1}});
});
```

**If i was to subscribe to other publications on individual routes in the waitOn function, will it override the 'userData' publication, or add to it?**